# Dynamic CDI Injection of beans

Tags: java, plugins, dependency-injection, cdi

Im trying to find a way to use injection in classes that are being loaded at run time,
i have succeeded in injecting them with already present beans using this method:

```
AnnotatedType<T> plugType=beanManager.createAnnotatedType(clazzT);
InjectionTarget<T> it = beanManager.createInjectionTarget(plugType);
T o=it.produce(ctx);
it.inject(o, ctx);
it.postConstruct(o);
```

the problem is when trying to inject a class that is not a loaded bean,
lets say i want to load two classes A and B and A has a field type of B injection- then injection of A fails on missing dependencies ,
the creation of B succeeded (later when trying to instantiate later) but this doesn't "register" the bean in the current bean-manager ,thus making my try to "double-pass" to ensure dependency fail.
tried looking into CDI portable extensions but it seems these needed to be explicitly declared in some file  - i'm looking for loading totally unknown entities (that might implement certain interface)

any ideas?

Comment: hk2 is a dynamic injection framework you might be interested in.  It is designed specifically to allow for loading later entities that were unknown at the time of initial boot, so it may be what you are looking for